# ZAP-CLI report generation

Tags: command-line-interface, zap

I am using `zap-cli` to scan some targets, and I want to generate a report in xml format, but cannot find a proper way to do it.

I run this command `zap-cli --zap-path /opt/zaproxy quick-scan https://google.com`.

What do I need to add to generate xml report?

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

From [Zap-cli](https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli) Readme:

`report       Generate XML, MD or HTML report.`

You can use `zap-cli` to find out how:

```
$ zap-cli report --help
Usage: zap-cli report [OPTIONS]

  Generate XML or HTML report.

Options:
  -o, --output TEXT               Output file for report.
  -f, --output-format [xml|html]  Report format.
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: thank you for answer.
I already saw that documentation, but I cant find a way to report xml properly.
so, my full command will be like this ? (zap-cli --zap-path /opt/zaproxy quick-scan https://google.com report Generate XML)

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try using the tool next time :)

Comment: great, glad that I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

In my case this work, first I need have open Windows applicaction ZAP 2.9.0, then I view the Api Key in Tools - Options - API. Also, I view the port, 8080.

Now in CMD, first, the I need a unique report by each new web site and not others old web sites:

```
zap-cli --api-key "my api key" -p "8080" session new
```

Then, execuite que analysis

```
zap-cli --api-key "my api key" -p "8080" -v quick-scan http://cmvqa.coordinacioncitamedica.cl
```

Finally the report

```
zap-cli --api-key "my api key" -p "8080" report -o ZAP_Report.html -f html
```